# User scalable iframe on iPhone

Tags: iphone, android

I have a web site that is designed to work best with mobile device browsers (iPhone, Android, and Blackberry). The default page of the site uses the following meta key to prevent the user from scaling the page using pinch gestures:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,height=device-height,user-scalable=no,initialScale=1.0,maximumScale=1.0"/>
```

In some cases, I am showing an image on this page, and I would like the user to be able to use pinch gestures to zoom in/out on *just* the image. One thought I had was to create an iframe when the user clicks (touches) the image. The iframe would contain a page with the image, and the following meta element designed to allow pinch gestures to scale the image:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,height=device-height,user-scalable=yes,initialScale=1.0"/>
```

But the image in the iframe is still not scalable. Is what I am trying to do even possible without navigating to a new page?

Comment: Was there a solution discovered for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can scroll on iframes on the iphone browser.